# QuickCheck Semigroup over a function

Tags: haskell

I have this method to test associativity for a Semigroup

```
semigroupdAssoc :: (Eq m, Semigroup m) => m -> m -> m -> Bool
semigroupdAssoc a b c = a <> (b <> c) == (a <> b) <> c
```

Given the following type

```
newtype Combine a b =
    Combine { unCombine :: a -> b }
```

My Semigroup implementation i

```
instance Semigroup b => Semigroup (Combine a b) where
    (<>) (Combine u) (Combine u') = Combine (u <> u')
```

I am stuck on how should I write a quick test,

Let's say I want to test for String,

```
type CombineAssoc = Combine String String -> Combine String String -> Combine String String -> Bool
```

And the test will be

```
    quickCheck (semigroupdAssoc :: CombineAssoc)
```

I know I have to write a `Arbitrary` implementation for `Combine` but I can't figure out how.

**Figured out solution, but I don't understand it.**

implementation of Arbitrary for Combine looks like this:

```
instance (CoArbitrary a, Arbitrary b) => Arbitrary  (Combine a b) where
    arbitrary = do
        Combine <$> arbitrary
```

need to implement Show also (not really great)

```
instance Show (Combine a b) where
    show (Combine _) = "unCombine"
```

Update the assoc function for this data type

```
combineSemigroupAssoc :: (Eq b, Semigroup b) => a -> Combine a b -> Combine a b -> Combine a b -> Bool
combineSemigroupAssoc x a b c = unCombine (a <> (b <> c)) x == unCombine ((a <> b) <> c) x
```

Implement the property that needs testing

```
genString :: Gen String
genString = arbitrary

prop_combineSemigroupAssoc :: Property
prop_combineSemigroupAssoc = forAll genString (combineSemigroupAssoc :: CombineAssoc)
```

and finally run quickCheck

```
    quickCheck prop_combineSemigroupAssoc
```

***Thinks I still need help with***

- Can you please explain how the Arbitrary implementation works now (docs for CoArbitrary are not very clear to me)?
- Is there a better way to implement Show for Combine, like see the actual call param?

Comment: You can't do this that way, since you have a function in the `Combine` object, and you can not check if two functions are equal (that is a consequence of Rice's theorem).

Comment: So I will have to apply function to some argument and try it out? I know that my semigroup implementation works because I can test it in ghci

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem QuickCheck is used all the time for checking (kinda) whether two functions are equal – not by actually showing that they're equal, but by failing to show they're nonequal.

Comment: I can do Gen for a simple `uncombine` function for String -> String, `\n -> n` (the identity)

Comment: @Calin: what you can do is for example work with a `semigroupdAssoc a b c x = uncombine (a <> (b <> c)) x == uncombine ((a <> b) <> c) x` with as signature `semigroupdAssoc :: (Eq b, Semigroup a) => Combine a b -> Combine a b -> Combine a b -> b -> Bool`

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it, I've tried with an updated version of the code `combineSemigroupAssoc :: (Eq b, Semigroup b) => Combine a b -> Combine a b -> Combine a b -> a -> Bool
combineSemigroupAssoc a b c x = uncombine (a <> (b <> c)) x == uncombine ((a <> b) <> c) x` and then wanted to write a property that can actually be passed to quickCheck but I still don't see how.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend writing your property in terms of [`Fun`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.14.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#t:Fun):

```
type SS = Fun String String -- just to shorten things a bit

prop_CombineAssoc :: SS -> SS -> SS -> String -> Bool
prop_CombineAssoc f_ g_ h_ s =
    unCombine (f <> (g <> h)) s == unCombine ((f <> g) <> h) s
    where
    [f, g, h] = map (Combine . applyFun) [f_, g_, h_]
```

The above property passes, but for fun, here's what it looks like for a failure. To get this output, I changed `(f <> (g <> h))` to just `f`.

```
> quickCheck prop_CombineAssoc
*** Failed! Falsified (after 3 tests and 16 shrinks):    
{_->""}
{_->""}
{_->"a"}
""
```

As you can see, the `Show` instance for `Fun` is more informative than simply returning a constant `String`, as your instance for `Combine` does.